# Pedometer is not working in iPhone 5

Tags: ios, accelerometer, iphone-5, motion, pedometer

The step counting using pedometer is not working in iPhone 5.
It working well in iPhone 5S and higher devices. Does the iPhone 5 has M7 coprocessor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the first phone with a M-series co-processor was the iPhone 5s. You can use `CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()` to check whether step counting is available on the device.